# Bundle VS. Chunk in webpack4

Tags: webpack, bundle

I am learning webpack right now. But it confused me with Bundle and chunk. I already done some search about these two concepts. But still not clear.
I did some test by myself:

```
entry: {
  app: './src/app.js',
  people: './src/people.js'
}
```

```
plugins:[
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: "[name].css"
    })
        // new WebpackBundleAnalyzer()
    ]
```

And after build:
[image]

What in my mind is:
These four lines are chunks, so what is bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of `Webpack`, a bundle is just a generated module resulting from building a dependency graph that maps every module your project needs. Under the hood, Webpack removes unused code, detect circular dependencies, minimize a code, etc. In the end, you'll get a ready to go module that can be included to the page.

The [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/glossary/) highlights the difference perfectly:

**Bundle:**

> Produced from a number of distinct modules, bundles contain
>   the final versions of source files that have already undergone the
>   loading and compilation process.

**Chunk:**

> This webpack-specific term is used internally to manage the
>   bundling process. Bundles are composed out of chunks, of which there
>   are several types (e.g. entry and child). Typically, chunks directly
>   correspond with the output bundles however, there are some
>   configurations that don't yield a one-to-one relationship.

When you're application is quite a big it's maybe meaningful to split up big bundles into chunks and load them lazily, generally speaking, it can decrease time loading dramatically.

There is a good module [LimitChunkCountPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/limit-chunk-count-plugin/#root) that can help you to detect too small chunks and merge them to decrease HTTP overhead.

Check out these related discussions [What are module, chunk and bundle in webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42523436/what-are-module-chunk-and-bundle-in-webpack#:~:targetText=Interpretation,chunk%20or%20set%20of%20chunks) and https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/970

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I will check out these :)